# Protractor Can't Find Element

Tags: protractor

Hi guys I have a problem with protractor. It cannot find the element I want to manipulate. [image]

In the picture above, the element inside the small red rectangle box is the attribute I use in my locator. When I ran protractor it gives an error saying it cannot find the element. So I console a getOuterHtml and this is what it displayed.

[image]

In the getOuterHtml() results the qa-rubric-optionInputTitle is can no longer be found. Can anybody explain to me why this happened?

Comment: Did you make sure that the attributes are not being changed dynamically, from your developer? Thanks

Comment: Please post the code showing how you tried to locate that element, and the actual error from the log.

Comment: I think this is because your browser close before it finds the element. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the browser needs to wait a little bit before an element becomes target-able (Since selinium is so fast!),I usually put in a browser.sleep(1000) in the protractor code and that usually sorts out the problem.